# Comparing a particular attribute of all records in a single table in MySQL and finding the greatest among them

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, window-functions

I have a table of employee (emp) in my database and what I want to do is to compare the salaries of all the employees and SELECT only those who has higher salary than the employee "Smith". I'm trying to do it using self join but output is not what I'm looking for. Here is the query I tried.

```
select t1.SAL from emp as t1, emp as t2 where t1.ENAME!="Smith";
```

here is the record of emp table:
[image: here is the record of emp table]

here's the schema of database in mysql:
[image: here's the schema of database in mysql]

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead post the code as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) for a link to easily create ascii tables of data.

Comment: whatever was in the image i've also posted in the form of text as well (was just a query)

Comment: I did see that. But I do not see your table, nor any sample data. Also, there seems to be missing expected results.

Comment: DDL & base table initialization is code & text & it's needed for a [mre] & it's not present. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a subquery for filtering:

```
select e.*
from emp e
where salary > (select salary from emp where ename = 'Smith')
```

Note that, for this to work properly, there must be only one row in the table whose `ename` is equal to `'Smith'`.

If you wanted to use a self-join:

```
select e.*, e1.salary smith_salary
from emp e
inner join emp e1 on e.salary > e1.salary
where e1.ename = 'Smith'
```

Finally, if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can also use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        e.*, 
        max(case when ename = 'Smith' then salary end) over() smith_salary
    from employee e
) e
where salary > smith_salary
```

Comment: But i'm supposed to do this using joins so could you help me out with that?

Comment: could you please let me know if could get it done with self join? is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a self join:

```
select e.*
from employees e join
     employees es
     on es.ename = 'Smith' and e.salary > es.salary;
```

This assumes that only one row matches "Smith".

Comment: @MohsinNazakat . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?